# laying out images on appjar

Tags: python, image, user-interface

So, I'm trying to lay out an image using appjar. I can already display it.
I have widgets in the next rows but if I add another column to the rows below the picture, it gets moved. I don't know how to set images in a specific position (row, column). Does anyone know?

```
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("picture.jpg"))
app.addImageData("pic", photo, fmt="PhotoImage")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more columns in one row than another, then things can get out of line.

You may need to tell your image to span multiple columns, try using the `colspan` parameter.

See here for more info: http://appjar.info/pythonWidgetLayout/#grid-layout

Eg.

```
app.addImage('demo', 'myImage.jpg', row=0, column=0, colspan=4)
app.addLabel('a', 'a', row=1, column=0)
app.addLabel('b', 'b', row=1, column=1)
app.addLabel('c', 'c', row=1, column=2)
app.addLabel('d', 'd', row=1, column=3)
```

Comment: You're right! I tried using just the parameters, I mean..
app.addImageData('demo', 'myImage.jpg', 0, 0, 4), and it doesn't work like that.
The way you suggested works. Thank you very much.